# Svelte reactivity and multiple dependencies - proper method of waiting until all dependences are present?

Tags: javascript, components, undefined, svelte, reactive

I am frequently running into situations where I have reactive statements that depend on multiple variables. Svelte does not wait to assign exported variable values from the calling component before reacting these statements, so I have to embedd all manner of checks on every variable to ensure they have been assigned before attempting to use them in a way that will raise a javascript error. Here's an example:

```
  $: entityName = dimensionListing.includes((node?.synonyms??{})[node?.entityNameSynonym]) ? getAttr(data,node?.entityNameSynonym) : undefined
  $: entityType = dimensionListing.includes((node?.synonyms??{})[node?.entityTypeSynonym]) ? getAttr(data,node?.entityTypeSynonym) : undefined

  $: displayDimensions=node.entityAttributes.filter((e) => (dimensionListing??[]).includes(e.columnName) &&
                                                           e.columnName !== (node?.synonyms??{}[node?.entityNameSynonym]) &&
                                                           !(entityName && e.columnName === (node?.synonyms??{}[node?.entityTypeSynonym])) &&
                                                           data[e.columnName])
```

In the first example (entityName), it reacts as soon as dimensionListing gets assigned, but before node is assigned... it will raise a javascript error about reading from an undefined if it attempts to resolve "node.synonyms", so I have to use the ?. operator to avoid that. But then the .synonyms property will be undefined, which will in turn raise an error if I attempt to read it with [], so I have to coallesce undefines to an empty object {} to avoid that error. And lastly, ever reference to node. has to be made into node.?

Something similar is happening on the third assignment, of displayDimensions. When it executes I don't know if it's because Svelte assigned dimensionsListing, data, node, or the reactive entityName, all of which are dependencies. One of them will have an assignment, the other two or three will not. So I have to add all the ?. and ?? to avoid javascript errors until all the values are assigned and I get a good reactive statement execution on the third or fourth try.

This doesn't seem elegant or simple to code.

Another option is:

```
$: displayDimensions = node && dimensionListing && data && entityName ? *function* : undefined
```

This at least avoids using ?. and ?? in the function. But that's still not very satisfying, that I would to find, identity and list every single dependency like this before every reactive statement.

Is there not a simpler way to set "don't run this reactive statement unless all dependencies are defined" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can put pretty much any arbitrary expression after `$:`. So you can just use an `if` statement:

```html
<script>
    let displayDimensions = undefined

    $: if (node && dimensionsListing && data && entityName) {
        displayDimensions = // Do your stuff
    }
</script>
```

I hope this is satisfying to you because I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to have reactive values react to just *some* of the variables.

Maybe you could consider using `onMount` if the problem arises because of `bind:this`. It might be that with the `nodes` but without more context its hard to give a more tailored answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sure, but again we're having to identify all dependencies manually and list them. I've been writing so many lengthy chains of &&s to check readiness all over the place it just seems like a weakness in Svelte.